# How to compute the limit of the following function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm looking for a way to compute the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(|x|^\beta-|x-c|^\beta\right),\quad c\in\mathbb{R},\,\beta\in(0,1).$$

My hypothesis is that this limit is equal to $0$ and the range of $\beta$ plays an important role because for $\beta\in[1,\infty)$ the claim fails. I've tried L'Hospital's Rule and the squeezing theorem. But so far, I didn't succeed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ large enough the quantities $x$ and $x-c$ are positive. Therefore we can ignore the absolute values.

$$f(x) = \vert x \vert^\beta - \vert x - c\vert^\beta=x^\beta \left(1 - \left(1-\frac{c}{x}\right)^\beta\right)$$

And

$$\left(1-\frac{c}{x}\right)^\beta = 1 - \frac{c\beta}{x} +o(\frac{1}{x})$$

Hence
$$f(x) =x^\beta \left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{c\beta}{x} +o(\frac{1}{x})\right)\right) = \frac{c\beta}{x^{1-\beta}} + o(\frac{1}{x^{1-\beta}})$$

Proving according to your intution that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Merci Claude! I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi Jean-Pierre ! Interesting website for sure. Are you working in university ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks! No, I'm an engineer who turn (badly ;-)) to sales activities. But I always was found of mathematics and studied by myself as a hobby. I was "agrégé" (also as a hobby) in 2012 but finally didn't switch to teaching. Your works in simulation were probably great!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the second row of your formulas, you are using the approximation (+errorterm) of the functionvalue with the help of the tangent, right?  In the last step, I would use the following: $x^{\beta}=o(x)$ and the errorterm in the approximation above is $g(x)=o(\frac{1}{x})$. This implies that $f(x)=\frac{c\beta}{x^{1-\beta}}+o(\frac{1}{x}x)$ which clearly shows the claim, right? For $x\to-\infty$ the limit is the same because of point-symmetry with respect to $\frac{c}{2}$. Am I right?